# Retrieving nodes having (or not) a child to apply a conditional template

Tags: xslt, parameters, selectnodes

I read lot of articles but did not find a conclusive help to my problem.

I have an XML document to which I apply an xslt to get a csv file as output.
I send a parameter to my xsl transformation to filter the target nodes to apply the templates.

The xml document looks like that  (I removed some unuseful nodes for comprehension):

```
<GetMOTransactionsResponse xmlns="http://www.exane.com/pott" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.exane.com/pott PoTTMOTransaction.xsd">
<MOTransaction>
    <Transaction VersionNumber="2" TradeDate="2013-11-20">
        <TransactionId Type="Risque">32164597</TransactionId>
        <InternalTransaction Type="Switch">
            <BookCounterparty>
                <Id Type="Risque">94</Id>
            </BookCounterparty>
        </InternalTransaction>
        <SalesPerson>
            <Id Type="Risque">-1</Id>
        </SalesPerson>
    </Transaction>
    <GrossPrice>58.92</GrossPrice>
    <MOAccount Account="TO1E" />
    <Entity>0021</Entity>
</MOTransaction>
<MOTransaction>
    <Transaction VersionNumber="1" TradeDate="2013-11-20">
        <TransactionId Type="Risque">32164598</TransactionId>
        <SalesPerson>
            <Id Type="Risque">-1</Id>
        </SalesPerson>
    </Transaction>
    <GrossPrice>58.92</GrossPrice>
    <MOAccount Account="TO3E" />
    <Entity>0021</Entity>
</MOTransaction>
</GetMOTransactionsResponse>
```

My xslt is below (sorry it's quite long, and I write it more simple than it really is):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:pott="http://www.exane.com/pott">

  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" />

  <xsl:param name="instrumentalSystem"></xsl:param>

  <xsl:template name="abs">
    <xsl:param name="n" />
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$n = 0">
        <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:when test="$n &gt; 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number($n, '#')" />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(0 - $n, '#')" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="outputFormat">
    <!--Declaration of variables-->
    <xsl:variable name="GrossPrice" select="pott:GrossPrice" />
    <xsl:variable name="TransactionId" select="pott:Transaction/pott:TransactionId[@Type='Risque']" />
    <xsl:variable name="VersionNumber" select="pott:Transaction/@VersionNumber" />

    <!--Set tags values-->
    <xsl:value-of select="$Entity" />
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0000000', pott:MOAccount/@Account) "/>
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$TransactionId" />
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$VersionNumber" />
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:choose>
      <!-- BB -->
      <xsl:when test="$instrumentalSystem = 'BB'">
        <!--xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction/pott:Transaction[pott:InternalTransaction]"-->
        <xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction/pott:Transaction[pott:InternalTransaction]">
          <xsl:call-template name="outputFormat"></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>

      <!-- CP -->
      <xsl:when test="$instrumentalSystem = 'CP'">
        <xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction/pott:Transaction[not(pott:InternalTransaction)]">
          <xsl:call-template name="outputFormat"></xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:when>

      <xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If parameter = BB, I want to select **MOTransaction** nodes that have a child Transaction that contains a *InternalTransaction* node.

If parameter = CP, I want to select **MOTransaction** nodes that don't have a child Transaction that contains a *InternalTransaction* node

When I write 
pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction/pott:Transaction[pott:InternalTransaction], I get the Transaction nodes and not the MOTransaction nodes
I think I am not very far from the expected result, but despite all my attempts, I fail.
If anyone can help me.

I hope being clear, otherwise I can give more information.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at one of **xsl:for-each** statements, you are doing this

```
<xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction/pott:Transaction[pott:InternalTransaction]">
```

You say you want to select **MOTransaction** elements, but it is actually selecting the child **Transaction** elements. To match the logic you require, it should be this

```
<xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction[pott:Transaction[pott:InternalTransaction]]">
```

In fact, this should also work

```
<xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction[pott:Transaction/pott:InternalTransaction]">
```

Similarly, for the second statement (in the case of the parameter being "CP"), it could look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction[pott:Transaction[not(pott:InternalTransaction)]]">
```

Alternatively, it could look like this

```
<xsl:for-each select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction[not(pott:Transaction/pott:InternalTransaction)]">
```

They are not quite the same though, as the first will only include **MOTransaction** elements that have **Transaction** child elements, whereas the second will include **MOTransaction** that don't have any **Transaction** childs at all.

As a slight aside, you don't really need to use an **xsl:for-each** and **xsl:call-template** here. It might be better to use template matching.

Firstly, try changing the named template `<xsl:template name="outputFormat">` to this

```
<xsl:template match="pott:MOTransaction">
```

Then, you can re-write you merge the **xsl:for-each** and **xsl:call-template** into a single **xsl:apply-templates** call.

```
<xsl:apply-template select="pott:GetMOTransactionsResponse/pott:MOTransaction[pott:Transaction/pott:InternalTransaction]" />
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. About the XPath query, you are right. It works fine. And about the merge into apply-templates, I will test it and will give you the result. But, thanks for your help and all the details.

Comment: Tim, double thanks. The code of my xslt is clearer, and everything works fine.